# Adding a progress bar to an existing Symfony2 entity form

Tags: symfony, jquery-file-upload

I've built a form which sends a video file to the server.

My client now wants a progress bar for some nicer UI.

Is it possible to drop in a JS script that can use the current form with no back end changes, or do I have to add some extra routes/methods for it to work?

This is what I've attempted.

Drop in the https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload plugin. This looks great, but I can't bind the form's submit button to the plugin, so the form just submits 'normally' and the plugin is not run (although the plugin is initializing OK).

I think the plugin wants to send the file on its own, but I need the whole form to be submitted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try [this bundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md). It give you integration with really good amount of plugins and you can choose one of them.

Anyway if you want progress bar, file must be send via ajax. You can upload file first and then submit form.

Comment: Thanks, although I'd already seen that bundle I had hoped to just make small modifications to the current code. It seems that I'll have to make more modifications.

Comment: Good bundle, easily integrated. Thanks the authors